# Disable taps on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I would like to disable the effect of the UIScrollView, that it cancels the current `setContentOffset` animation when tapped. However, panning should still be recognized at any time.

The reason is that I have implemented custom page-sizes (By using the UIScollView delegate's method `- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset`, where I set `targetContentOffset`, such that it is a valid page bound).

If a user now taps while an animation is going on, the UIScrollView cancels the animation, which I want to avoid, because it leaves the UIScrollView with an invalid contentOffset.

Comment: Hey Erik, this is a very old question but I'm facing the same issue now. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method, `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`, which tells you when a scroll view animation caused by calling `setContentOffset:animated:` completes. I ended up setting `scrollEnabled` to `NO` on the scroll view before I call `setContentOffset:animated`, then setting it back to YES in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`. Effectively the user can't tap to cancel the scroll animation.

Comment: Doing this he can't pan while scrolling and he said he needed this feature